# How to show InterstitialAd after X amout of clicks

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, plugins

I am using the cordova-plugin-admob-free, when the variable totalQuestions equals to six the first time, it shows the InterstitialAd without a problem, then the variable becomes 0 and after 6 more clicks, the ad won't show. What am I doing wrong? I guess I have to request a new ad or perhaps do something differently?

At the top of the JS file I have this:

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
    admob.interstitial.config({
        id: 'ca-app-pub-9044971602164437/7052812839',
        autoShow: false
    });

    admob.interstitial.prepare();
}
```

And I have this function further down:

```
$(".truth-btn, .dare-btn").on("click", function (event) {
    totalQuestions++;
    if (totalQuestions == 6) {
        admob.interstitial.show();
        totalQuestions = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prepare another interstitial like this

```
let totalQuestions=0;
$(".dare-btn").on("click", function (event) {
    totalQuestions++;
    console.log(totalQuestions);
    if (totalQuestions == 6) {
        admob.interstitial.show();
        totalQuestions = 0;
        setTimeout(() => { 
              admob.interstitial.prepare();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

> and it is better to use localstorage to save the value of totalQuestions

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm. Yes indeed, just need to fix this issue :D